# Mapping Longitude and Latitude

Tags: java, eclipse

So I have multiple ship objects and each ship has a series of correlating Longitude and Latitude coordinates stored showing its route. 
Ex.

```
[Longitude: 28.780815 Latitude: 60.259568
, Longitude: 28.780402 Latitude: 60.259393
, Longitude: 28.780585 Latitude: 60.259897
, Longitude: 28.78109 Latitude: 60.259785
, Longitude: 28.780408 Latitude: 60.259422
, Longitude: 28.781125 Latitude: 60.259893
, Longitude: 28.780835 Latitude: 60.259447
]
```

My hope is to somehow plot each ship's coordinates on a map to get an overall idea of a ship's path. 

Using java[eclipse], I'm looking to create a graphic mapping of the coordinates, but am having problems trying to find a good library/tool to do this.

Comment: This is pretty broad question, but you can get away with using an ArrayList, HashMap, Map, etc...

Comment: Each ship object has an identifier and a ArrayList<Coordinates>, I'm trying to find a Gui that I can map the coordinates.

Comment: Have you checked SourceForge?

Comment: I had no luck with SourceForge, I found a library called GeoTools, working through the tutorial now, but I'm not sure if it'll do what I'm looking for.

Comment: You should contact the author and ask...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try kml files.

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream); 
                            out.write("<kml>"); 
                            out.write("<Folder>");

                            out.write("<Placemark>");
                            out.write("<name>"+entry.getKey()+"</name>");
                            out.write("<LineString>");
                            out.write("<extrude>1</extrude>"); 
                            out.write("<tessellate>1</tessellate>");
                            out.write("<altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>");
                            out.write("<coordinates>");
                            for(int i=0; i<entry.getValue().getCoordinates().size(); i++){ //path creation 
                                out.write(entry.getValue().getCoordinates().get(i).getLongitude()+","+
                                        entry.getValue().getCoordinates().get(i).getLatitude()+" ");
                            }
                            out.write("</coordinates>");
                            out.write("</LineString>");
                            out.write("</Placemark>");

                            for(int j=0; j<entry.getValue().getCoordinates().size(); j++){ //point creation 
                                out.write("<Placemark>");
                                out.write("<name>"+entry.getValue().getCoordinates().get(j).coordinates()+"</name>");
                                out.write("<tessellate>1</tessellate>");
                                out.write("<altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>");
                                out.write("<Point>");
                                out.write("<coordinates>");
                                out.write(entry.getValue().getCoordinates().get(j).getLongitude()+","+
                                        entry.getValue().getCoordinates().get(j).getLatitude());
                                out.write("</coordinates>");
                                out.write("</Point>");
                                out.write("</Placemark>");
                            }

                            out.write("</Folder>");
                            out.write("</kml>");
                            out.close();
                        }
```